# Discord bot that posts custom welcome message

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want my bot to post a simple welcome message in a 'welcome' text channel for every new member.

I've read a lot of posts here and there but still having trouble with making it work as intended

**Here is the code:**

```
console.log('Beep Boop Beep'); //prints 'Beep Boop Beep'

require('dotenv').config(); //load the dotenv node pachage and call a config() func to load thea values from .env

const {Client, MessageEmbed} = require('discord.js');

//EDIT: const client = new Client()
const client = new Client({ ws: { intents: [
    'GUILDS',
    'GUILD_MESSAGES',
    'GUILD_PRESENCES',
    'GUILD_MEMBERS'
] } });

const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("DM thing")
    .setColor(0xFF0000)
    .setDescription("Add describtion here")

client.login(process.env.BOTTOKEN); 

module.exports = {client, embed};

function readyDiscord() {
    console.log('readyDiscord func executed. Discord is ready.'); 
}

client.on('ready', readyDiscord);

const commandHandler = require('./commands'); 

client.on('message', commandHandler);

//EDIT: 'guildMembersAdd'
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => { 
    console.log(member)

    const message = `Hey, <@${member.id}>! Welcome. DM me if anytime you want.`
    
    //EDIT: const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(WELCOME_CHANNEL_ID)
    const channel = await 

//EDIT: pocess.env
member.guild.channels.resolve(process.env.WELCOME_CHANNEL_ID);
    channel.send(message)
})
```

PRESENCE INTENT and SERVER MEMBERS INTENT are enabled.
Each time i try to add a Test Account bot spits out those errors:

**Errors:**

```
(base) admin@MacBook-Pro-11 discord_binder % node bot.js
Beep Boop Beep
readyDiscord func executed. Discord is ready.
GuildMember {
  guild: <ref *1> Guild {
    members: GuildMemberManager {
      cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],
      cache: [Collection [Map]],
      guild: [Circular *1]
    },
    channels: GuildChannelManager {
      cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],
      cache: [Collection [Map]],
      guild: [Circular *1]
    },
    roles: RoleManager {
      cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],
      cache: [Collection [Map]],
      guild: [Circular *1]
    },
    presences: PresenceManager {
      cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],
      cache: [Collection [Map]]
    },
    voiceStates: VoiceStateManager {
      cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],
      cache: Collection(0) [Map] {},
      guild: [Circular *1]
    },
    deleted: false,
    available: true,
    id: '779767191012638721',
    shardID: 0,
    name: 'testovoe_nazvaniye',
    icon: '0b54ebc0b473b6571b8157d207392af0',
    splash: null,
    discoverySplash: null,
    region: 'russia',
    memberCount: 5,
    large: false,
    features: [],
    applicationID: null,
    afkTimeout: 300,
    afkChannelID: null,
    systemChannelID: '779768178296750080',
    embedEnabled: undefined,
    premiumTier: 0,
    premiumSubscriptionCount: 0,
    verificationLevel: 'NONE',
    explicitContentFilter: 'DISABLED',
    mfaLevel: 0,
    joinedTimestamp: 1620485504837,
    defaultMessageNotifications: 'ALL',
    systemChannelFlags: SystemChannelFlags { bitfield: 0 },
    maximumMembers: 100000,
    maximumPresences: null,
    approximateMemberCount: null,
    approximatePresenceCount: null,
    vanityURLCode: null,
    vanityURLUses: null,
    description: null,
    banner: null,
    rulesChannelID: null,
    publicUpdatesChannelID: null,
    preferredLocale: 'en-US',
    ownerID: '660217837016842260',
    emojis: GuildEmojiManager {
      cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],
      cache: Collection(0) [Map] {},
      guild: [Circular *1]
    }
  },
  joinedTimestamp: 1620486298424,
  lastMessageID: null,
  lastMessageChannelID: null,
  premiumSinceTimestamp: 0,
  deleted: false,
  nickname: null,
  _roles: [],
  user: User {
    id: '462330953734291457',
    system: null,
    locale: null,
    flags: UserFlags { bitfield: 0 },
    username: 'Test Account',
    bot: false,
    discriminator: '4317',
    avatar: '343601cdd6da4d03329351def9ffbffb',
    lastMessageID: null,
    lastMessageChannelID: null
  }
}
(node:2459) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: pocess is not defined
    at Client.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/Desktop/projects/re_bot/discord_binder/bot.js:43:57)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Object.module.exports [as GUILD_MEMBER_ADD] (/Users/admin/Desktop/projects/re_bot/discord_binder/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/GUILD_MEMBER_ADD.js:16:14)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/Users/admin/Desktop/projects/re_bot/discord_binder/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/Users/admin/Desktop/projects/re_bot/discord_binder/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/Users/admin/Desktop/projects/re_bot/discord_binder/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/Users/admin/Desktop/projects/re_bot/discord_binder/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/Users/admin/Desktop/projects/re_bot/discord_binder/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:825:20)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:315:20)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:2459) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2459) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

EDIT:

The overall idea of code was right, but there were lots of typos which you see as //EDIT: comments. So maybe you want to go and check your code for same typos

Comment: You try to get a channel using `WELCOME_CHAHHEL_ID`, is it supposed to be `WELCOME_CHANNEL_ID`? Furthermore, log your variable to confirm it returns a valid id

Comment: @Elitezen Thanks for your comment, i fixed the typo but the bot still does not work. I updated my question with all edits and the error that it started to output to the console

Comment: The first thing in your output is a guildMember object, the 2nd - which is actually an error - says "pocess" is undefined. Did you mean `process`?

Comment: @Elitezen Thanks a lot, it works now. So the problem turned out to be my typos. But my client.on('message', commandHandler) thing stopped working and bot no longer reacts on messages. My closest assumption is that i messed up the use of sync/async functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have a comment in your code saying that `WELCOME_CNAHHEL_ID` is an environment variable. Just like what you did with `BOTTOKEN`, you might want to prefix the variable with `process.env`, so it should look like this:

```js
process.env.WELCOME_CHANNEL_ID
```

You also have a typo in your original code: `CNAHHEL` instead of `CHANNEL`. Make sure the name on the .env file and the name you use in your code match.

Comment: I updated the code with all the suggestions from the answers including yours. It still does not work. The importand think i think is the fact that 'console.log(member)' does not output anything. So that that part of code simply does not word

Comment: I updated my question with all edits and the error that it started to output to the console. Please, check to see if you can help with that.

Answer (score 2):

Could you let us know what is being logged to the console from the `console.log(member)`?

My best bet would be that the WELCOME_CHANNEL_ID is wrong and thus returning a bogus channel.

If that is not the case, then maybe the bot is not caching the channels, so use this:

```
const channel = await member.guild.channels.resolve(WELCOME_CHANNEL_ID);
```

Let us know if it doesn't work.

Comment: I updated the code with all the suggestions from the answers including yours. It still does not work. The importand think i think is the fact that 'console.log(member)' does not output anything. So that that part of code simply does not word

Comment: @NEOdinok The commend by Akio is correct, you misspelled the event, it should be guildMemberAdd without the s in Member.

Comment: I fixed all types and updated my question with all edits and the error that it started to output to the console. Bot still does not seem to word properly. Please, check to see if you can help with that.

Answer (score 2):

**Just enabling Intents in Developer Portal dosen't mean you're using Intents**
You'll have to tell your client which intents to use.

So, Instead of

```js
const client = new Client();
```

You need to do

```js
const client = new Client({ ws: { intents: [
    'GUILDS',
    'GUILD_MESSAGES',
    'GUILD_PRESENCES',
    'GUILD_MEMBERS'
] } });
```

This will tell the client to load the **GUILD_MEMBERS** Intent so that you can use `guildMemberAdd`

This code should work after that. Comment if any error.

**Edit: In your code you've misspelled `guildMemberAdd` for `guildMembersAdd` You should also fix that.**

**Resource:**

- [How to use intents](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html)
- [Official Docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway)

Comment: I updated the code with all the suggestions from the answers including yours. It still does not work. The importand think i think is the fact that 'console.log(member)' does not output anything. So that that part of code simply does not word

Comment: @NEOdinok It's `guildMemberAdd` not `guildMembersAdd` ( Note the s )

Comment: I fixed all types and updated my question with all edits and the error that it started to output to the console. Bot still does not seem to word properly. Please, check to see if you can help with that.

Comment: About your new error: It's `process` not `pocess`